# How to allow jenkins builds on several cores?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins

I am using Jenkins on a small test server that has only two cores.

I noticed that jenkins binds each build to a core, i.e., if a job is launched it will use only one core.

My tests are essentially matrix operations and I need jenkins to use several cores per build.

Is there a plug-in to enable this feature?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/architecting-for-scale/ - Add more agents for doing build or tests or any real tasks

Comment: What I meant is that the build in Jenkins runs on one core it is not using the full capacity of the server. I am disabling the concurrent build option in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into the same issue. Jenkins is multicore by default. My issue was that I was running an R application and it turns out that the base linear algebra library of R does not multithread. Installing a parallel library https://csantill.github.io/RPerformanceWBLAS/ enabled multithreading.